# Migrating Azure VM to make use of 12 months free services

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

My Azure 200$ free credits are expiring in 3 days , so i am trying to move my VM's & App Services to free to avoid incurring any charges. I dont want to delete my VM since it has all my code configured in Visual Studio and my environment is set up there.

I used below link to see what all services are free for 12 months , the list i see includes 750 hours of VM compute for B1S VM.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/free-account-faq/

I have already downsized my VM from DSv2 to B1S VM's. My question is regarding the VM Disk i am using , how to make sure it is using from the free quota . I see the link mentions that we have for 12 months free 128 GB of Managed Disks as a combination of two 64 GB (P6) SSD storage, plus 1 GB snapshot and 2 million I/O operations​ .

I am currently using a premium 128 GB LRS managed disk . However i could not find if i am using a P6 disk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

128 GB premium is P10, therefore not eligible for the free tier. I suggest starting fresh with a new VM and migrate the content as there's no easy way to shrink a managed disk. If you want to give it a try, see this article:

[How to shrink a managed disk](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/01/26/how-to-shrink-a-managed-disk/)

Comment: Thanks Bruno , any easy ways i can migrate the data ?
I have seen the link above before and it seems rather complicated and cumbersome not to mention a bit risky as well.

Comment: why not use the free VSTS repository? https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/ You can also use Azure File Share to transfer files between two VMs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno ! i am going to try using a file share . I have a VSTS account but don't think i should be uploading the files there.

Comment: no worries. Please don't forget to mark this as an answer if it works for you. cheers.

Comment: Bruno , one more question i have is where i can select the P6 disk while creating the new VM. Apparently it does not give me an option to do so. I am using an image which contains VS 2017 Community preinstalled.

Comment: It’s the size. P6 is 64GB. You don’t actually see the disk type when creating a VM. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview#benefits-of-managed-disks

Comment: Thanks Bruno , however i cannot seem to find a place where it asks me to specify the size for the managed disk as well. I just get an option to select the sizing of the VM which i select as B1S VM.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I think the only way using the Portal is to search for "Free account Virtual Machine" in the Marketplace. This will deploy the VM using a JSON Template instead with the correct parameters to make sure you get the Free Tier benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno for this information , i will surely try this option and then manually install Visual Studio Community 2017 on it , since it can't be done using a preinstalled image.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You, I have sucessfull convert the original images of 128GB (P10) to 64GB (P6) to get REAL ACCESS to the free tier. I want to mention that I am new to Azure, so most of the terms are new to me (even the P6 and P10 thing) and after much research I can conclude that there is no such thing as free tier out of the box, there is no single image suitable for P6 disk on marketplace, thus is imposible to get real free tier just by sing in. The only way to get access to free tier is following the complex tuturial of this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/01/26/how-to-shrink-a-managed-disk/

Is not an easy task because there are a lot of steps that are not mentioned and also a lot of terms that someone new to azure like me don't know, but it's work and i am the proof of it.

In the tutorial the most important things missing are:
-You got to run the first part in PowerShell on the VM that you want to convert (but this only works in some OS like Win10 but not in Win7) if you want to resize in an OS that dont support the Resize-Partition command you got to use a Partition software to do it. (there are a lot of freeware available for this)

-The second part must run in the PowerShell available in Azure Portal (you enter to this clicking the ">" next to notifications, and then select PowerShell intead Batch mode)

-Finally, tune up the variables is the main problem, because you got to create a lot of resources before use it, but the tutorial dont show this. Then you got to figure out how/where get and grant access, keys, and so on.
Most of the resources needed are charged (not included in free tier), so you got to do this in the first 30 days of the free tier (when you still got some credit of the initial $200)

BTW delete all the resources used to acomplish this is a must if you want free tier, because StorageBlobs are not part of the free tier.

Regards